# Laravel whereIn issue (array expected, int given) error

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent

```
public function store(OrderCreateRequest $request)
{
    $formField = $request->validated();

    $totalAmount = 0;
    
    // get the price of products of product_id using whereIn
    $products =  DB::table('products')
         ->select('price')
         ->whereIn('id', $formField['product_id'])
         ->get();


    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $totalAmount += $product->price;
    }
   
    $order = Order::create([
        'product_id' => $formField['product_id'],
        'user_id' => Auth::id(),
        'total' => $totalAmount,
        'status' => false,
    ]);


    $response = [
        'message' => 'order placed',
        'created' => new OrderResource($order),
    ];

    return response($response, 201);
}
```

what is wrong with this piece of code?

error:

```
Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize(): Argument #1 ($values) must be of type array, int given,
```

Comment: Hi, the second parameter of whereIn should be an array, then this `$formField['product_id']` must be an array of ids, if you really want to check if this id exists on an array of ids. But if you just want to compare if where the is is exists in the database, just use `whereId($formField['product_id'])` or `where('id', $formField['product_id'])`.

Answer (score 3):

You are giving an int to `whereIn()`, whereIn is a function to check a column value against multiple values.

```
->whereIn('status', ['pending', 'completed'])
```

In your case either `product_id` should be an `array`, or you should just use a simple `where()`.

```
->where('id', $formField['product_id'])
```